# Spark - Efficient way of reading multiple versions of S3 object into DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I want to read N last versions of an S3 object and put them all into a Map[version, DataFrame] structure. Each S3 object is a json lines file of approximately 2 GB each. S3A client does not support passing versionId as far as I can see, so I cannot use this approach. Can anyone suggest an efficient alternative approach? The only thing I can think of is to create normal AmazonS3 client and get S3 object using SDK. However, I'm not too experienced in Spark/Scala and not sure how to then convert it into DataFrame.

Comment: if you have a directory for each version, you can use the parent directory and loop over to construct the path for each version then use spark.read.csv("path") to read it as a dataframe. If you use EMR you shoud have access rights to S3

Comment: @firas what do you mean by directory? S3 object versioning feature stores versions under the same bucket/key just using different versionId

Comment: ah Ok I see. I don't know how to precise the version when reading S3 bucket with spark

Comment: There's no support for anything like that...nothing like a Posix filesystem and so not in the APIs or connectors used. Even if something was added at the s3a level, it's not anything which the normal RDD code would expect/handle when they listed a directory

Comment: @TofigHasanov, Is there any way to list out all the different versions of same object in a particular folder in Spark?